# Cannot start rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Im trying to start my server (command rails s) at my place and it's not working. It worked perfectly when i was at school, now it's not...

This is the error that show's :

```
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/ftp.rb:273:in `getresp': 530 Login authentication
failed (Net::FTPPermError)
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/ftp.rb:294:in `block in sendcmd'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/ftp.rb:292:in `sendcmd'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/ftp.rb:396:in `block in login'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/ftp.rb:392:in `login'
        from c:/rails/aroundthetable/config/application.rb:8:in `<top (required)
>'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/comman
ds.rb:53:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/comman
ds.rb:53:in `block in <top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/comman
ds.rb:50:in `tap'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/comman
ds.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
        from script/rails:6:in `require'
        from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Can you guys please help?

Comment: Please show us the file `c:/rails/aroundthetable/config/application.rb:8:in`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're connecting to a FTP server somewhere in your code and the authentication failed.